# Asterisk: Record application is generating empty files

Tags: asterisk

User making the call is asked to dial an extension. This is done by 1#playing a prompt with **Background** and then 2#wait_for_digit. Based on the extension that has been dialed, the destination number is determined and the call is forwarded to that number.

If the called person doesn't not answer, then **Playback** is used to play a prompt that asks the user to record the voice message; recording the voice message is done with the **Record** application.

This **Record** application is always generating empty wav files, size 44 bytes. If I remove the 1#playing a prompt with **Background** the **Record** application is generating proper files. If the **Background** is included, all recordings are empty.

I am using Perl Asterisk::AGI module.

```
$agi->exec('Answer');
....
.....
$agi->exec('Background', 'en/extra/please-enter-the-extension,n'); # this is the troubling part
my $my_extension = $agi->wait_for_digit(5000);
....
.....
$agi->exec('Playback', 'en/extra/the-party-you-are-calling&en/extra/is-curntly-busy,noanswer');
$agi->exec('Playback', 'en/vm-intro,noanswer');
my $file = 'xyz.wav';
$agi->exec('Record', "$file,0,10,k");
...
...
```

What should I do to make it work as I want it to?

Thank you.

UPDATE 1:
The same script is working without glitches now. Not sure if something unrelated to the script has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likly you have check your codecs. IF you use g729 or g723 and no transcoder,it just can't write in wav format.

Comment: It is writing in wav format when I remove the call to the "Background" before the "wait_for_digit". So, I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: okay. but i am 90% sure issues as i described. check channel codec and try record in same format or add translation.